# How do I check if objects in a frame are loaded yet or not after a gotoAndStop(5) action?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am facing a problem, where there is a function executed the next line right after a gotoAndStop(130) action, the function depends in its work on the objects inside this frame. but the problem is that the function seems not seeing any children.. why? why? why? why?

```
myMc.gotoAndStop(130);
create_waypoints(par1,par2,par3);
```

the function `creat_waypoints` depends on the drawn obstacles that exists in frame 130 inside the `myMc`.

it seems (but I don't know for sure) by the time that `creat_waypoints` executes its actions, frame 130 was just entered but not yet loaded...

What can I do? Thanks in advance..

after many experiments, I have come to a working solution but it is twisted, it had to skip an entire loop of actions and I am not happy with it, but for now it is all what I have..

```
myMc.gotoAndStop(2);  
myMc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mc_ef,false,0,true);  
function mc_ef(e:Event):void {  
  if (e.target.loaded==null) {  
      e.target.loaded=true;  
  } else {  
      e.target.loaded=null;  
      creat_waypoints(par1,par2,par3);  
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.type,arguments.callee);  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler work-around would be including the "obstacles" and their dependencies in earlier frame where the depending logic is written.  They can be included as "out-of-stage" invisible members.

Comment: I am afraid this solution can't help my case, because each frame in  myMc contains different obstacles objects, and I want the function to execute on whatever is drawn or shown by myMc..